# Can't get a specific flexbox child to form to it's container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get my flexbox to conform to it's container but I seem to be missing a step but can't figure out what.

Attached snippet. It's within the media query but I added the whole code incase it helps. You'll notice my `.f` is to the right. It should be sharing both lines of `.b` and `.c .d .e`

```css
body {
  background: papayawhip;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  row-gap:10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.a{
  background-color: teal;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 20vh;
}
.b{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 40vh;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.c{
  background-color: #264b75;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 20vh;
}
.d{
  background-color: #773535;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 20vh;
}
.e{
  background-color: #e3b036;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 20vh;
}
.f{
  background-color: #74446f;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 20vh;
}
.nonsense{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
/* desktop version */
@media (min-width: 300px){
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.broad{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 60vh;
}
.b{
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 60vw;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.f{
  width: 20vw;
  height: 60vh;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.nonsense{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 60vw;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="broad">
        <div class="b">b</div>
      <div class="nonsense">
        <div class="c">c</div>
        <div class="d">d</div>
        <div class="e">e</div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="f">f</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build page layout with flexbox? If so maybe look into CSS Grid as it's more flexible and can support a multi dimensional layout. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: @Arty.Simon I know, I did it with Grid no problem. I'm just trying to attempt flexbox now but having problems.

Comment: Gotcha, if I understand the issue correctly. You want to see column f span between row `b` and row `c,d,e`?

Comment: @Arty.Simon Correct. So F would share the same line as B and C D E

Comment: The `.broad` flex item (containing b, c, d and e), takes up more space than you think. There's no reason for f to be positioned there. You would need to use additional HTML wrappers, absolute positioning, or Grid. https://jsfiddle.net/74boc9z5/

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin even changing `.broad` and `.c .d .e` to have a smaller vw doesn't move the `.f` class into it. So are you saying it just can't be done without more wrappers?

Comment: I agree with @MichaelBenjamin, looking at his fiddle example, you'll see that the `.broad` container (red border) is in the way of `.f` moving to your desired spot regardless of vw.  Restructuring your HTML with more wrappers and nested flexbox could get you the desired result but might be a headache in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each element is given width and height values in vw. When you give the container of the elements a general value, you can adjust the sub-elements by giving the width in percent.

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
        background: papayawhip;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
      }
      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 70vh;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .a {
        background-color: teal;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
      }
      .b {
        background-color: aliceblue;
        width: 80vw;
        height: 75%;
      }
      .c {
        background-color: #264b75;
        width: calc(100% / 3);
        height: 100%;
      }
      .d {
        background-color: #773535;
        width: calc(100% / 3);
        height: 100%;
      }
      .e {
        background-color: #e3b036;
        width: calc(100% / 3);
        height: 100%;
      }
      .f {
        background-color: #74446f;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .nonsense {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        gap: 10px;
        height: 25%;
      }
      /* desktop version */
      @media (min-width: 300px) {
        .container {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-direction: row;
          width: 90vw;
          margin: 0 auto;
          row-gap: 10px;
        }
        .broad {
          display: grid;
          height: 80%;
          width: 100%;
          gap: 10px;
          grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
        }
        .leftSide {
          flex: 0 0 70%;
          row-gap: 10px;
        }
        .rightSide {
          flex: 0 0 30%;
          height: calc(100% + 10px);
        }
        .b {
          width: 100%;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .f {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        .nonsense {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="a">a</div>
      <div class="broad">
        <div class="leftSide">
          <div class="b">b</div>
          <div class="nonsense">
            <div class="c">c</div>
            <div class="d">d</div>
            <div class="e">e</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightSide">
          <div class="f">f</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```